# How to reduce the timer's time while timer is running (ActionScript 3.0)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, timer

In my case, the timer I make doesn't reduce its time whenever a function is called. What code will I change or add in order to reduce the time in my timer?

Timer code:

```
var count:Number = 1200;
var lessTime:Number = 180;
var totalSecondsLeft:Number = 0;
var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000, count);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, countdown);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, timesup);

function countdown(event:TimerEvent) {
    totalSecondsLeft = count - timer.currentCount;
    this.mainmc.time_txt.text = timeFormat(totalSecondsLeft);
}

function timeFormat(seconds:int):String {
var minutes:int;
var sMinutes:String;
var sSeconds:String;
if(seconds > 59) {
    minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    sMinutes = String(minutes);
    sSeconds = String(seconds % 60);
    } else {
    sMinutes = "";
    sSeconds = String(seconds);
}
if(sSeconds.length == 1) {
    sSeconds = "0" + sSeconds;
}
return sMinutes + ":" + sSeconds;
}

function timesup(e:TimerEvent):void {
    gotoAndPlay(14);
}
```

At this point the `timer.start();` is placed on a frame so that the timer starts as it enters the frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `delay` property on `Timer` is what you are looking for. In your handler, change the timer's delay:

```
function countdown(event:TimerEvent)
{
    totalSecondsLeft = count - timer.currentCount;
    this.mainmc.time_txt.text = timeFormat(totalSecondsLeft);

    //change the timer delay
    timer.delay -= lessTime;
}
```

I assumed by your code sample that you wanted to subtract `lessTime` from the timer delay on each timer interval. If you want to change the delay to something else, then just adjust the code accordingly.

**UPDATE**
The above code is for decreasing the interval (`delay`) between each timer fire. If what you'd like to do instead is decrease the the amount of intervals (`repeatCount`) it takes for the timer to reach `TIMER_COMPLETE`, then you want to change the `repeatCount` property on `Timer`:

```
//set the timer fire interval to 1 second (1000 milliseconds)
//and the total timer time to 1200 seconds (1200 repeatCount)
var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000, 1200);

//reduce the overall timer length by 3 minutes
timer.repeatCount -= 300;
```

**ANOTHER UPDATE**
Keep in mind that when you alter the `repeatCount`, it doesn't affect the `currentCount`. Since you are using a separate `count` variable and `timer.currentCount` to calculate the displayed time remaining, it doesn't look like anything is changing. It actually is though - the timer will complete before the displayed time counts down to zero. To keep your time left display accurate, make sure to subtract the same amount from `count` as you are from `repeatCount`:

```
timer.repeatCount -= 300;
count -= 300;
```

Comment: when i run the program, adding the code, my timer decrease faster than normal seconds count. what I'm trying to do is when a listener is activated the timer will decrease by 3 minutes. is that possible?

Comment: What do you mean, "decrease by 3 minutes"? Right now your timer interval starts by firing every second (1000 milliseconds). You can't decrease that interval by 3 minutes. Are you talking about the timer interval (delay) or the time it takes to hit `TIMER_COMPLETE`?

Comment: I'm trying to get the timer to decrease by 3 minutes after 10 consecutive clicks on the screen. but my timer i dont know how to decrease the time after a function is called here is the code for the function i made: this.missedclicks = 10; this.mainmc.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, clickOb1); //missclick
function clickScreen (e:MouseEvent) {
 this.missedclicks--;
 if (this.missedclicks==0) {
   //change the timer delay
     timer.delay -= lessTime;
  this.missedclicks=5;
  }
}

Comment: I've edited the answer to provide the code needed for reducing the overall timer time (the time it takes until `TIMER_COMPLETE` is fired). The answer covers the only two adjustable parameters available on `Timer` for manipulating time - `delay` for adjusting the timer interval and `repeatCount` for adjusting how many times the timer fires.

Comment: it has no effect on the timer. how can i update the timer after the repeat count?

Comment: I need more info. The code I posted should change the `repeatCount` of the timer. Did you put it in the mouse click handler you mentioned you wanted it to go?

Comment: yes i did put it in a different function. this is the flow of my project. I have 2 layers, one layer is for the timer and the other is for the frames. after a few frames the timer will start together with the stage where in object are spread on a picture and you need to find the object by clicking on them, on every wrong click lets say 10 wrong clicks the timer must decrease to 3 minutes by means of a mouse click listener. but my timer does not decreasing. the code above is the code of my timer. and the other code i wrote earlier is the code for missclicks which has an mouse click listener.

Comment: Ah, the problem is with how the time left is being calculated, not the timer itself. I've updated the answer again.

Comment: Wherever you want to reduce the timer. So if you want the timer to reduce on a user click, then put it in the mouse click handler.

Comment: i put it in my mouse click function and still it has no effect on the timer. what seems to be the problem? i'm losing hope... what will i do...

Comment: Here is the working code: http://pastie.org/3532048 It creates the textfield and button programmatically so I could show you that it works. You can paste this into a fresh AS3 Flash project and publish and see it working.

Comment: wow your code works i'll just insert it in mine. thanks a lot ^_^

Comment: ilollar the timer decrease works, but when the click decrease another 3 mins when timer is a minuets away from zero, the timer stops but then nothing is happening. what seems to be the problem?

Comment: Modified: http://pastie.org/3538863 You need to check in the `reduceTimer` method if the `repeatCount` is lower than zero - if it is lower than zero then the timer will stop without firing complete.